# How to pass function as props in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have functional component GetWeather which I want to pass result of  GetLocation function as props based on which GetWetaher will do something i.e. another get request (in the example below it only renders its props). I think it has to happen inside ComponentDidMount, not sure how to do it

```
    function GetLocation() {
        axios.get('http://ipinfo.io')
          .then((res) => {      
            return res.data.loc;
          })

      }
    function GetWeather(props) {
    //more code here, including another get request, based on props
        return <h1>Location: {props.location}</h1>;    
    }

    class LocalWeather extends Component {           
      componentDidMount() {    
        //???     
      }          
      render() {
        return (
          <div >                         
                <GetWeather location={GetLocation}/> //???                                               
          </div> 
        );
      }
    }
```

**Update:** So based on suggestion from Damian below is working for me

```
function GetWeather(props) {   
    return <h3>Location: {props.location}</h3>;   
}

class LocalWeather extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      location: []
    }; 
  }
  getLocation() {
    axios.get('http://ipinfo.io')
      .then((res) => {       
        this.setState({location:res.data.loc});        
      })         
  }

  componentDidMount() {    
    this.getLocation();     

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div >                       
            <GetWeather location={this.state.location}/>                                                 
      </div> 
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more elaborate with your questions, it seems a little bit vague to me.  But from my understanding so far, you can just create a default state in your `LocalWeather` component constructor, then in your `componentDidMount` make a call to get location and set the return value to the `LocalWeather` component After which you can pass the location to the `GetWeather` component as props via the state of the `LocalWeather` component.

Comment: I think you got my question right...and it works for me now;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it alternatively also

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    Location:[]
  }
}

function GetLocation() {
  axios.get('http://ipinfo.io').then((res) => { 
    this.setState ({
      Location:res.data.loc;
    });
  });
}

function GetWeather(props) {
  return <h1>Location: {this.props.location}</h1>;    
}
    
class LocalWeather extends Component {           
  componentDidMount() {    
    //code     
  }          

  render() {
    return (
      <div >                         
        <GetWeather location={this.GetLocation.bind(this)}/>                                            
      </div> 
    );
  }
}
```