# onClick event on stateless components controlling a prop on that Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a stateless component called `EmailItem`: I want to be able to give it a new prop via some function when I click on it.

```
<EmailItem key={i} onClick={// onClick function} emailData={email} read={false} />
```

I want the value of `read` prop to change to true when the `EmailItem` is clicked.

I understand this can be done by making `EmailItem` a stateful component; however, it is an iterable component and from my understanding adding state where you don't NEED it, is bad. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I am confused about the content of the function I would use since **e.target** and **refs** will not work.

This `read` prop will change the class of an item in the stateless component.

```
const EmailItem = (props) => {
  let readClass = props.emailData.read ? '--read' : ''
  return (
    <div onClick={props.onClick} className='email'>
      <div className={'email__read' + readClass} />
      <div className='email__leftside'>
        <div className='email__from'>{props.emailData.from}</div>
        <div className='email__subject'>{props.emailData.subject}</div>
        <div className={'email__body'}>{props.emailData.body}</div>
      </div>
      <div className='email__rightside'>
        <div className='email__date'>{props.emailData.date}</div>
        <div className='email__time'>{props.emailData.time}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `email__read` className is an indicator of whether the email has been read or not

Comment: If you are using redux or similar, dispatch action, else pass function (from parent) to this component and call it in onclick

Comment: @PriyeshKumar I am using Redux and I am aware of this ability. But I know you can't use refs to reference a stateless component. And the event.target does not show props, only html attributes. I am more confused about the content of the function I would use.Sorry for not being clear in original post.

Comment: It would be more understandable if you can put component code, and context(what you are try to do)   ^_^

Comment: @PriyeshKumar done

Comment: Why you need e.target or refs. To update emaildata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understood, You can pass function(onClick) from parent to child component and bind emaildata to that function. ES6 arrow function syntax takes care of parameter binding and you can get emailData(which was clicked) in parent.

Try out following example(sorry for no css)

```
class Inbox extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      emails: [
        { read: false, from: "aaa", to: "aaato", subject: "aaasubject", body: "aaabody", date: "aaadate", time: "aaatime" },
        { read: true, from: "bbb", to: "bbbto", subject: "bbbsubject", body: "bbbbody", date: "bbbdate", time: "bbbtime" },
        { read: false, from: "aaa", to: "cccto", subject: "cccsubject", body: "cccbody", date: "cccdate", time: "ccctime" },
        { read: false, from: "ddd", to: "dddto", subject: "dddsubject", body: "dddbody", date: "ddddate", time: "dddtime" },
      ]

    }
  }

  handleClick(index, ele) {
    // ele is emaildata, do anything you want
    var newEmails = this.state.emails

    newEmails[index].read = true
    this.setState({
      emails: newEmails
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Emails</p>
        {
          this.state.emails.map((e, i) => {
            return <EmailItem emailData={e} key={i} onClick={() => { this.handleClick(i, e) }} />
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const EmailItem = (props) => {
  let readClass = props.emailData.read ? '--read' : '--unread'
  return (
    <div onClick={props.onClick} className='email'>
      <div className={'email__read' + readClass} />
      <div className='email__leftside'>
        <p>{readClass}</p>
        <div className='email__from'>From {props.emailData.from}</div>
        <div className='email__subject'>To {props.emailData.subject}</div>
        <div className={'email__body'}>Body {props.emailData.body}</div>
      </div>
      <div className='email__rightside'>
        <div className='email__date'>Date {props.emailData.date}</div>
        <div className='email__time'>Time {props.emailData.time}</div>
      </div>

      <p>---------------------</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: This I can see would work perfectly. It is just for some reason I am bothered by keeping the records of all emails in state. It seems like a big memory hog when these records can reach 10,000's. But I guess this is normal.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I don't think you are planning to display all list in one go, if you are then you have not choice. Else you can use pagination to get emails what need to be shown. And keep only them in state

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do to change your props is to change the state. It doesn't matter that the state doesn't live in this component. You can pass callback from your parent component and than call this callback inside your stateless component and change state in your parent component.
Note: State doesn't to be in the parent. It can be higher up.
This should help you: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

I hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: So your saying I should save the state of all the email items read status in the higher component? For some reason I feel like making the state on a component that big is too intensive. I'm not sure how much state is too much.

Comment: Yes, you should aim for 'one source of truth' big state object, rather than multiple states all over. Is much better to reason about when you have state in one place. Since it's just an object it's fast and cheap and react will handle the rest for you (like updating DOM). I think you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

May be this link can help you i jut gave its answer there

[How to pass function as props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720361/how-to-pass-function-as-props-in-react/43720689#43720689)

Comment: Yeah I know how to pass a function to a component as a prop. I am more confused about the content of the function I need to pass.