# How to pass callback functions inside React.createElement() using React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a parent component inside it is a SideNav and a child component which is made using React.createElement(). Now I want to pass the state changes from Child Component to SideNav.
For that I need to pass the state to Parent Component which can then be used in SideNav.
But I am not getting how to add the callback function using React.createElement() which can be used in Parent Component.

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: '',
      changes: '' //This I need from child component's state
    }
    
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
  }
 handler(id) {
    this.setState({
      data: id
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Row>
          <Col className="col-3">
            <SideNav data={this.state} props={this.props} onChange={this.handler} />
          </Col>
          <Col>
            {React.createElement(
              ChildComponent, {
              data: this.state.data
              //Here I need to add the callback function used for getting state change from Child component
            }
            )}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Please suggest how to use callback inside React.createElement().

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why are you using React.createElement at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass function as props in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43720361/how-to-pass-function-as-props-in-react)

Comment: Yes, actually you are right, I should not be using React.createElement, I took a reference from my project. I achieved the same without using it too. Thank you for the guidance @talfreds